# If is multiple page templates

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

Via functions.php, I'm trying to enqueue specific scripts and styles based on two separate page templates. Here's what I've tried:

```
if ( !is_page_template('page-templates/page-index.php') && !is_page_template('page-templates/page-contact-us.php') ) {

        // Map
        wp_enqueue_script('google-map', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'map', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/map.js', array('jquery'), '20160408', true );

        // Map markers
        wp_enqueue_style( 'markers-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/map_markers/css/map-icons.min.css', array(), '20160409', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'markers', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/map_markers/js/map-icons.min.js', array('jquery'), '20160408', true );    
    }
```

I'm expecting the scripts to enqueue on page-index.php and page-contact-us.php when I visit the pages assigned to those page templates. They are not enqueuing at all with the current code.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what action are you hooking too? this is likely the problem... suggest it should be `wp_enqueue_scripts`. also note `is_page_template` cannot be used inside the loop.

Comment: I'm working through the function: `function theme_scripts() {` via functions.php using the _s theme.

Comment: What do you mean with "this doesn't seem to be working"? Are the script enqueued incorrectly? Are not they enqueued at all? When do you want they be enqueued exactly, when you are in those page templates or when you are not in those page templates?

Comment: I'm expecting the scripts to enqueue on page-index.php and page-contact-us.php when I visit the pages assigned to those page templates. They are not enqueuing at all with the current code.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253820/how-to-use-if-is-page-template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I you want the script be enqueued on page-index.php and page-contact-us.php, then you must check that that page templates are used but you are checking if they are not used.

Chagne this:

```
if ( !is_page_template('page-templates/page-index.php') && !is_page_template('page-templates/page-contact-us.php') ) {
```

with:

```
if ( is_page_template('page-templates/page-index.php') || is_page_template('page-templates/page-contact-us.php') ) {
```

The first code reads like: if is NOT page-templates/page-index.php AND it is NOT page-templates/page-contact-us.php ...

The second conditional reads like: if IS page-templates/page-index.php OR it IS page-templates/page-contact-us.php ....

You can use also an array of page templates to be checked:

```
if ( is_page_template( array( 'page-templates/page-index.php', 'page-templates/page-contact-us.php') ) ) {
```