# How to use if (is_page_template (''))

Tags: functions

i use the following code in my functions.php. I want to exclude all pages which use the single.php template.

```
function cat_menu() {

 if (!is_page_template('single.php')) {


$cur_cat = get_query_var('cat');

 $new_cats = wp_list_categories('echo=false&child_of=' . $cur_cat .'&depth=1&title_li=&&show_count=0&hide_empty=1');
            echo '<ul>' . $new_cats . '</ul>';
}}
  add_action ( 'genesis_after_header', 'cat_menu' );
```

But i see the result aslo on pages which use the single.php.

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_page_template()` checks against post type templates specified by the theme using

```
/**
 * Template Name: My Template
 */
```

at the top of the template file. Not any arbitrary template file. For this, you might wanna check out the answers over at [Get name of the current template file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10537/get-name-of-the-current-template-file). You could grab the code from the accepted answer there (`get_current_template()`) to do something when `single.php === get_current_template()`.

Answer (score 0):

You must to use the next function:

```
is_singular()
```

Is singular checks if current page is single.php.

[Function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)

Comment: `is_singular()` doesn't 100% guarantee that `single.php` was loaded, as other templates in the hierarchy might be loaded before it.

Answer (score 0):

It's always strange to me how long it takes WPSE threads to receive accurate answers, here is a basic example of how to use it from StackOverflow:

```
// if not specific page template
<?php if (!is_page_template('page-templates/all-sponsor-template.php')); ?>
    // Stuff
<?php endif; ?>

// if is specific page template
<?php if (is_page_template('page-templates/all-sponsor-template.php')); ?>
    // Stuff
<?php endif; ?>
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531957/if-is-page-template-not-working-in-header-php

Answer (score -1):

get_page_template_slug() - Returns only the page template

```
 global $post;    
    $template = get_page_template_slug($post->ID);         
    if ($template == 'page-template.php') {....}
```

Probably worth checking out easier

```
if(is_single()){....}
```

Comment: This is the same problem as with `is_page_template()`. `get_page_template_slug()` only checks for custom post templates (the ones with the `/* Template Name: ... */` headers). Also, `is_single()` doesn't 100% guarantee that `single.php` was loaded, as other templates in the hierarchy might be loaded before it.